# What are the common quality issues seen in collectible minifigs?

Tags: collectable-minifigures, quality

TLG is currently seeking specific feedback on what quality issues may be present within the Collectible Minifigures line so that these issues can be addressed. What are the common issues that you have seen?

It would be most helpful if answers could include detailed photos or data to support issues. For example, if there's an issue with color consistency, a comparison photo would be helpful. If there's an issue with clutch power, data would be great. I'll pass the feedback on to TLG by sending a link to this question once it gets some solid answers.

Answer (score 1):

I own a lego movie 2 minifig (flashback lucy) and the head piece is much harder to turn then usual, but that might just be because it's brand new.